# Make a field accessible to ONLY its corresponding property?

Tags: c#, .net

Say we have a private backing field and a private property exposing that field. Does C# support attributes or any other syntax to force a compiler error if any code, even code inside the class, attempts to access or modify the field except for the property without encapsulating the field and property in their own object? Please see a simple example below.

```
/// <summary>
/// Class to cache and quickly access data. Please only use this class if 1) the data to be cached  uses little memory and 2) the number of DB reads is high and could cause a performance strain.
/// </summary> 
class BMIDataCache
{
    #region fields
        protected static BMITimedDictionary<String, Device> _devices;
    #endregion

    #region properties
    protected static BMITimedDictionary<String, Device> Devices
    {
        get
        {
            if (_devices == null)
            { 
                _devices = new BMITimedDictionary<String, Device>();
                //Do some other stuff later.
            }
            return _devices;
        }
        set
        {
            _devices = value;
        }
    }
public void Test1()
{ //Inside this method, trying to access _devices will cause a compiler error, but not Devices
}
}
```

Comment: No you can't. A private member is available to all methods in the class. A protected member is available to all methods in the class or to any class which inherits from it.

Comment: Looks like something like this *should* be possible with Roslyn, though you would need some sort of convention, because the compiler doesn't have a sense that "this field A is the backing field of that property B".

Comment: My immediate thought on this is "that's another class" - you have a value and a behavior and you want complete control over that value and behavior.

Comment: Do you not trust your own code?

Comment: In principle, you should not "trust your own code" more than is comfortable. That's one major reason for the principle of encapsulation. I understand that I can derive from a class with a private field and protected property, or just leave it as is, but I think it's reasonable to ask if there's some syntactically simpler and cleaner way to accomplish this in C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing in C# that can help you hide `private` field from members of the same class.

Your options:

- some post-processing (i.e. custom plugin for code analysis with FxCop)
- move this fields/properties into base class and mark fields `private`. Than add real code to derived class - so derived class will not be able to reach fields
- use containment with interfaces instead.

Side note: you'll not be able to hide fields from reflection...

Comment: Nice tips...You got me searching and I found this link re containment http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/inheritance-vs-containment/